# Observable emits no value

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, rxjs-observables

I am new to Observables. I am using a switchMap to loop through an array of Observables from firestore, retriving two streams, combining the outputs of the streams into a new Observable Array.

```
createSuperPolicy( product:VehicleProducts, vehicle:Vehicle, id:String, policyCertID:String) : Observable<SuperVehiclePolicy>{

    var temp = new SuperVehiclePolicy;
   
    
      temp.policyID =  id,
      temp.vendor =  product.vendor,
      temp.title  = product.title,
      temp.premium = product.premium,
      temp.offer = product.offer,
      temp.reg = vehicle.registrationNumber ,
      temp.benefits = product.Benefits,
      temp.policyCertID =  policyCertID 

      
     

    return of(temp)
  }

  populateVehiclePolicyList = this.vehiclePolicyService.getPolicies().pipe(
       switchMap((policies:VehiclePolicy[]) => {
         var policyList$: Observable<SuperVehiclePolicy>[] = [];
         policies.forEach(policy => {
          var product$: Observable<VehicleProducts> = this.vehicleProductService.getProductByID(policy.vehicleProductID)          
          var vehicle$: Observable<Vehicle> = this.vehicleService.getVehicleByID(policy.vehicleID)
          var id$ = of(policy.id)
          var certID$ = of(policy.policyCertID)

          combineLatest(product$, vehicle$, id$,certID$)
          .pipe(map(([product, vehicle, pid,certID]) => this.createSuperPolicy(product,vehicle, pid, certID)))
          .subscribe((val) => policyList$.push(val));     
         });
         
         console.log(policyList$)
         return forkJoin(policyList$);     
       })
     )
```

Calling viewing the contents of the new Array of Observables(policyList$) displays the contents of the array.

Now when I subscribe to populateVehiclePolicyList, as below,

```
this.displayService.populateVehiclePolicyList.subscribe(((policy: SuperVehiclePolicy[]) => {console.log(policy)}))
```

Console.log(policy) returns neither a value nor an error.
I am confused as to what is happening.
How can I successfully subscribe to populateVehiclePolicyList, so as to consume the output?

Comment: Why would you do this: `return temp as unknown as Observable<SuperVehiclePolicy>`? You know there is a [creation operator called `of`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/of) that you can use to convert a value to an observable that emits this value straight away and then completes.

Answer (score 1):

there are few issues in your code so before I share the proper code, let me explain them a lil bit:

```
return  temp as unknown as Observable<SuperVehiclePolicy>
```

`as` keyword doesn't actually cast to different types, it just tells typescript to treat one thing as something other so you can't cast a variable of type `SuperVehiclePolicy` into `Observable<SuperVehiclePolicy>` like this, typescript won't complain as you are using `as` but you'll get problems in runtime, for this purposes rxjs provides an operator called `of` that you did use inside that switchMap

you are first converting your object to unknown so that you can then convert it to `Observable<SuperVehiclePolicy>`, that's just wrong cuz by doing this, you're basically hiding the symptoms instead of curing the disease.

```
var policyList$: Observable<SuperVehiclePolicy>[] = [];
```

don't use var, it's dead, use either let or const, [read this](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/var-let-and-const-whats-the-difference/)

```
combineLatest(product$, vehicle$, id$,certID$)
      .pipe(map(([product, vehicle, pid,certID]) => this.createSuperPolicy(product,vehicle, pid, certID)))
      .subscribe((val) => policyList$.push(val));
```

you are subscribing manually inside switchMap, don't do that, **generally** don't subscribe inside an rxjs operator as most of the time this is not what you actually want to do.

now why doesn't `console.log(policy)` logs anything?
you are providing`forkJoin(policyList$);` to your `switchMap` which is good but because you subscribing manually to above mentioned `combineLatest`, switchMap didn't wait for it and by the time you started pushing inside policyList$, your switchMap was already done. Hope this helps you understand why subscribing inside an operator is sometimes not what you actually want.

Ok lets jump onto the right code:

```js
class DisplayService {
    createSuperPolicy(product: VehicleProducts, vehicle: Vehicle, id: String, policyCertID: String): SuperVehiclePolicy {
        const temp = new SuperVehiclePolicy();

        temp.policyID = id;
        temp.vendor = product.vendor;
        temp.title = product.title;
        temp.premium = product.premium;
        temp.offer = product.offer;
        temp.reg = vehicle.registrationNumber;
        temp.benefits = product.Benefits;
        temp.policyCertID = policyCertID;

        return temp;
    }

    populateVehiclePolicyList = this.vehiclePolicyService.getPolicies().pipe(
        switchMap((policies: VehiclePolicy[]) => {
            const policyList$: Observable<SuperVehiclePolicy>[] = policies.map(policy => {
                const product$: Observable<VehicleProducts> = this.vehicleProductService.getProductByID(policy.vehicleProductID);
                const vehicle$: Observable<Vehicle> = this.vehicleService.getVehicleByID(policy.vehicleID);

                // build super policy for current policy and return it in an observable
                return forkJoin([product$, vehicle$]).pipe(
                    map((product, vehicle) => this.createSuperPolicy(product, vehicle, policy.id, policy.policyCertID))
                );
            });

            return forkJoin(policyList$).pipe(
                tap(superPolicies => {
                    console.log("Super policies: ", superPolicies);
                })
            );
        })
    );
}
```

notice that you don't need to return `Observable<SuperVehiclePolicy>` from `createSuperPolicy`

let me know if you have any doubt regarding above code, Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Couple of issues arose. Firstly , the line ` const policyList$: Observable<SuperVehiclePolicy>[] = policies
          .map(policy....`  gave an error  "Type 'Observable<Observable<SuperVehiclePolicy>>[]' is not assignable to type 'Observable<SuperVehiclePolicy>[]'." To try fix this I made the createSuperPolicy function return just a superVehiclepolicy object. Secondly the last line `console.log("Super policies: ", superPolicies)` didnt display any information to the console

Comment: hmm that's odd, in case if you are still facing issues, can you please create sample on https://stackblitz.com/